# Is there any advantage in enforcing implementation of hashCode and equals by making them abstract?

Tags: java, abstract-class, equals, abstract, hashcode

I just stumbled over [`abstract AbstractUnit` of the uom-se project](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/uom-se/blob/master/src/main/java/tec/uom/se/AbstractUnit.java#L520) which declares

```
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Ensures that sub-classes implements hashCode/equals method.
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Override
public abstract int hashCode();

@Override
public abstract boolean equals(Object that);
```

Either the framework needs `hashCode` and `equals` which check for equality internally, then the implementation should be done in the framework itself or it's up to the user to override these methods or not. The latter case this decision has to be done for *any* Java class anyway because of the way it's implemented in `Object` and what identity and equality comparison means in Java and in programming in general. So what could be the purpose of such a declaration?

This smells like an anti-pattern because the declaration is unnecessary for programmers who know what they're doing and lures those who don't into overriding it with `super.equals/hashCode` or creating an implementation which they don't need or want.

Comment: The purpose is to ensure that anything that extends from AbstractUnit implements `hashCode` and `equals`, likely because everything in the library depends on having a uniform mechanism for sorting/storing/etc. The impl *is* done in the framework for classes the framework provides, and *cannot* be done for classes the framework user creates. I'm not sure what the question is really asking.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm fairly sure I understand `equals` and `hashCode` and really can't think of a use case where that applies. I'd be really interested in one, though.

Comment: It's a unit of measure library. Users may add arbitrary units of measure. Why *wouldn't* you enforce implementation's that would likely be required for proper library functioning? I don't understand an argument for leaving them optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said:

> The latter case this decision has to be done for any Java class anyway...

It does indeed need to be done, but without those declarations, nothing forces the author of a subclass of `AbstractUnit` to actually do it, because there are default implementations on `Object`. So the declaration serves the purpose of forcing authors of subclasses to implement `hashCode` and `equals` as appropriate to their subclass rather than leaving them out. This at least eliminates the common cause of error that the subclass author didn't even think about needing to do that. (It can't, sadly, eliminate the second common cause of error: Authors doing so incorrectly.)

---

Re your edit:

> This smells like an anti-pattern...

Whether it's an anti-pattern is a matter of opinion and thus off-topic for SO.

> ...because the declaration is unnecessary for programmers who know what they're doing...

That many authors *don't* understand the need to override both `equals` and `hashCode` in a compatible way has been **very** well-established.

> ...and lures those who don't into overriding it with `super.equals/hashCode`

They can't. `super`'s version is `abstract`.

> ...or creating an implementation which they don't need or want.

Clearly, if they're writing a subclss of `AbstractUnit`, they **do** need to implement `equals` and `hashCode`; the authors of `AbstractUnit` have obviously determined that A) The versions from `Object` will not work correctly with `AbtractUnit`'s logic, and B) They can't provide a reasonable default. So they've forced subclass authors to implement them, in the only way they can: By declaring them `abstract`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added a note about possible anti-pattern to the question, in case you're interested to make up an argument to defend this practice.